# Error in setting QComboBox cellwidget

Tags: pyqt, qtablewidget, qcombobox

I am trying to set the index of a QComboBox that was created using `setCellWidget` which is set inside a QTableWidget
Why is it that despite me calling the combobox using `cellWidget`, I got an error while trying to set its index despite its type is still a QComboBox?

```
for row in xrange(self.table.rowCount()):
    combo = self.table.cellWidget(row, 1)
    print type(combo) # returns <type 'PySide.QtGui.QComboBox'>
    combo.setCurrentIndex(2)
```

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setCurrentIndex'
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  It's likely there is an error in your larger application that isn't present in your example code.

Comment: There is no way the above code is equivalent to what you are running because if the print() statement prints that the return type is combo, then the combo object cannot be None. Run the code that you post, and post exactly the code you run (code for an MCVE is recommended)